# Is it temporary materialization conversion applied to the operand of the const_cast

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, const-cast

```cpp
int main(){
  const_cast<int&&>(0);
}
```

According to [expr.const.cast#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const.cast#4)

> For two object types T1 and T2, if a pointer to T1 can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to T2” using a const_­cast, then the following conversions can also be made:
>
> > - an lvalue of type T1 can be explicitly converted to an lvalue of type T2 using the cast const_­cast<T2&>;
> > - a glvalue of type T1 can be explicitly converted to an xvalue of type T2 using the cast const_­cast<T2&&>; and
> > - if T1 is a class type, a prvalue of type T1 can be explicitly converted to an xvalue of type T2 using the cast const_­cast<T2&&>.

> The result of a reference const_­cast refers to the original object if the operand is a glvalue and to the result of applying the temporary materialization conversion otherwise.

Since the operand `0` is a prvalue of type int and the specified type is rvalue reference of type int. Hence, the second bullet can be applied here after performing the temporary materialization conversion that make the origin operand to be a glvalue as per [expr#basic.lval-7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr#basic.lval-7)

> Whenever a prvalue appears as an operand of an operator that expects a glvalue for that operand, the temporary materialization conversion is applied to convert the expression to an xvalue.

However, this [snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/rGzP3f) is rejected by both Clang and GCC. If we change the operand to `int{0}`

```cpp
int main(){
  const_cast<int&&>(int{0});
}
```

Only [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/afGesf) accepts the code. But the following code still cannot be compiled by [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/1cY6h5)

```cpp
int main(){
  const_cast<int&&>(int(0));
}
```

I don't know what's the difference here when the operand is `0`, `int{0}`, and `int(0)` respectively. In my mind, they're all **prvalue** of int type.

```cpp
typedef int *A[3];  
typedef const int *const CA[3];
int main(){
   A &&r2 = const_cast<A&&>(CA{}); 
}
```

This code is a formal example of [expr.const.cast#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const.cast#3). Unfortunately, it's rejected by [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/fK1MdY).

I don't know whether it could be considered as a defect of the standard or an incorrect implementation of Clang?  I don't know what's the intent of the third bullet of [expr.const.cast#4], why does it special mention the prvalue of class type?(Does it intend to say that only a prvalue of class type will be applied temporary materialization to it? However, it obviously contradicts with the example for prvalue of the array type).

Comment: [CWG1965](http://wg21.link/cwg1965)?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer It appears to me that whenever a glvalue is expected as an operand of an operator, the general rule [expr#basic.lval-7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr#basic.lval-7) should bring the original operand(prvalue) to a glvalue except that the rule explicitly forbids this conversion(temporary materialization conversion). If it's not, [expr#basic.lval-7] will be a bit of contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is **if T1 is a class type**. The type `int` is not a class type so 4.3 does not apply. If you used a `std::string`, it would work:

```
const std::string && x = const_cast<std::string&&>(std::string("foo") + "bar");
```

Comment: So, how do you interpret the formal example in the below part of [expr.const.cast#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const.cast#3)? Array is not a class type.